# Assign class instance property a value based on its type in Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I don't know if this is allowed in Typescript, but I'm working in an Angular 7 project and I want to instantiate a `Page` class fullfilling all his properties from DB object. These are my classes:

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    created_at: string;

    constructor(obj?: any) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

export class Page {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    author: User;


    constructor(obj?: any) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }

    showTitle(): string {
        return this.title;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of my service method to retrieve the data:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Page } from '../models/page';

@Injectable()
export class PageService {

    constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getPage(id: number): Observable<Page> {
        return this.httpClient
                   .get<Page>('http://<my-server-ip>:<port>/api/pages')
                   .pipe(
                       map((page: Page) => {
                           console.log('retrieved', page);
                           return new Page(page);
                       })
                   );
    }
}
```

And here is an example of this function call in my component

```
export class MyCustomComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(pageService: PageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pageService.getPage()
            .subscribe((page: Page) => {
                console.log(page.showTitle());
            });
    }
}
```

This example works, but when I want to access to `User` methods, like:

```
console.log(page.author.getName());
```

I don't have access to them because it is not an instantiation of `User` class.

The same would happen with `Page` if I do not return a new instance of page class as an observable, thats why I use `return new Page(page)` after retrieving the data.

The problem is that I want to keep my constructors as generic as possible, so creating a constructor to assign the value manually (e.g.: `this.author = new User(obj.author);`) is not a valid workaround, as I want to implement it in every model or create a `GenericModel` then extend all my models.

Is there a way to fill a property with defined type in a instantiated class depending in its type?

This is what I tried so far, but it doesn't work:

```
export class Page {
    // ...
    constructor(obj?: any) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach((key: string, index: number) => {
            if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object' && obj[key] !== null) {
                this[key] = new (this[key].constructor)(obj[key]);
            } else {
                this[key] = obj[key]
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of null
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

I understand that `this` is null when constructor is called, but I couldn't find another way to fill `author` property with a `new` instance to access to methods. Also, if I get a standard/default object like `{ ... }`, the `if` will trigger and probably will throw an error too, as it does not have a constructor.

Comment: Maybe you should use generics on that class to pass the type of one argument in particular and access that methods. [Generics typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval That is what I was thinking, but I dunno how can I achieve that. When I receive the `json` data from the server, I need to convert it in class instantiations and, if I have an `object` property, I need to instantiate that object property into a class somehow (based on its property name or doing a relationship aka mapping `author => 'Models\author.ts'`). Any ideas? Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.assign` like this:

```
getPage(id: number): Observable<Page> {
    return this.httpClient
               .get<Page>('http://<my-server-ip>:<port>/api/pages')
               .pipe(
                   map((page: Page) => {
                       console.log('retrieved', page);
                       return Object.assign(new Page(), page);
                   })
               );
}
```

This code creates a new Page instance and then copies over all of the properties from the returned response (`page` in this example).

Then you don't need to modify your constructors.

**UPDATE**

NOTE: The spread syntax only copies over the properties, so I changed to use `Object.assign` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm actually doing that in the constructor of `Page` class, as I mentioned in my Q. The problem is that inside that class I have a property that has its own class type `author: Author`. Using your example, which is the one I'm using, does not fill the author property instantiating the author class like `new Author();`, it only fills the data as a generic object. Filling it like a new instantiation is a must, because I need to access to `Author` class methods. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough in my Q.